# How to add vertical ad banner into Twenty Fifteen theme's right and left float?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Tried to put left or right float banner into twenty fifteen theme but this code didn't work: It only shows at left corner and broken the desktop and mobile version of site.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width:500px) {    #RightFloatAds{

    right: 0px;

    position: fixed;

    text-align: center;

    top: 0px;

    }

    }
```

To put ads code in header php like this:

```
<div id=”LeftFloatAds”> your ads code here </div>

<div id=”RightFloatAds”> your ads code here </div>
```

It didn't work and not proper way. How to fix?

Comment: The definition of your media query is never true: (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width:500px)

Comment: recheck your media query

Comment: so what should ii replace with?

Comment: you need to define separately both.